# How to delete last path component of a String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a String `11/Passion/01PassionAwakening.mp3` and I need to delete the last path component `01PassionAwakening.mp3` in order to get `11/Passion`.

How can I do this while saving both components?

Comment: The NSString documentation has an entire section about "Working with Paths" ...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can separate your url into two parts like so:

```
let str : NSString = "www.music.com/Passion/PassionAwakening.mp3" 
let path : NSString = str.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent
let ext : NSString = str.lastPathComponent

print(path)
print(ext)
```

## Output

```
www.music.com/Passion
PassionAwakening.mp3
```

For more info please have a look at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/ManipulatingPaths.html).

Comment: Note that this method only works with file paths (not, for example, string representations of URLs).

Comment: What do you mean by string representation?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/stringByDeletingLastPathComponent

Comment: in reality, i don't understand what apple means by that note ... :-)

Comment: @FredericAdda Actually right now i am not using swift, if anything apple changed then you can modify my answer. Anyways thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Doesn't work in Swift 3.0, but answers below show how to do it.

Comment: @user3441734: It means it can be used with `@"/Users/user/Desktop/Picture 07.png"` but not with the `absoluteString` representation of the URL: `@"file:///Users/user/Desktop/Picture%2007.png"`.

Answer (score 20):

You should really do away with legacy `NS` Objective-C classes and manual path string splitting where possible. Use `URL` instead:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "a/b/c.dat", isDirectory: false)
let path = url.deletingLastPathComponent().relativePath // 'a/b'
let file = url.lastPathComponent // 'c.dat'
```

That being said, Apple has an explicit [FilePath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/system/filepath) type starting with macOS 11, but with no path manipulation methods. For those you'd have to include the external [system package](https://github.com/apple/swift-system)

If you are on macOS 12, the methods from the external package are now also available on the system.

Comment: Best answer, but be careful!  Note if your filename contains spaces, for instance -- even if they are escaped with preceding backslash -- that `URL(fileURLWithPath:` substitutes "`%20`" for each space (and note that using `URL(string:` instead will promptly fail!)...  Also, if any of the directory names in your path contain whitespace or special characters, keep in mind that they will be "percent escaped" as well.

Comment: If you want to go the extra mile, use `URL(fileURLWithPath:,isDirectory:)` to avoid an extra file system access to check if the URL points to a directory. From the docs: `This function avoids an extra file system access to check if the file URL is a directory. You should use it if you know the answer already.`

Comment: `.path` (instead of `. relativePath`) would work as well.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4+:**

```
let components = path.split(separator: "/")
let directory = components.dropLast(1).map(String.init).joined(separator: "/")
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let str = "11/Passion/01PassionAwakening.mp3"
if !str.isEmpty {
    let components = str.characters.split("/")
    let head = components.dropLast(1).map(String.init).joinWithSeparator("/")
    let tail = components.dropFirst(components.count-1).map(String.init)[0]

    print("head:",head,"tail:", tail) // head: 11/Passion tail: 01PassionAwakening.mp3
} else {
    print("path should not be an empty string!")
}
```

Comment: Swift 3.0.1 requires syntax: split(separator: "/")

Answer (score 6):

This works for Swift 3.0 as well:

```
let fileName = NSString(string: "11/Passion/01PassionAwakening.mp3").lastPathComponent
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3.0 version

```
if !str.isEmpty {
        let components = str.characters.split(separator: "/")
        let head = components.dropLast(1).map(String.init).joined(separator: "/")
        let words = components.count-1
        let tail = components.dropFirst(words).map(String.init)[0]

        print("head:",head,"tail:", tail) // head: 11/Passion tail: 01PassionAwakening.mp3
    } else {
        print("path should not be an empty string!")
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

rolling back to NSString:

extension String {

```
var ns: NSString {
    return self as NSString
}

var pathExtension: String {
    return ns.pathExtension
}

var lastPathComponent: String {
    return ns.lastPathComponent
}

var stringByDeletingLastPathComponent: String {
    return ns.deletingLastPathComponent
}

}
```

so you can do:

```
let folderPath = pathString.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent
```

Answer (score 1):

Just improvised the solution for URL String. Thank you so much ingconti

```
extension String {

    var ns: URL? {
        return URL.init(string: self)
    }

    var pathExtension: String {
        return ns?.pathExtension ?? ""
    }

    var lastPathComponent: String {
        return ns?.lastPathComponent ?? ""
    }

    var stringByDeletingLastPathComponent: String {
        return ns?.deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: "Improvised", did you mean improved? And since this handles URL shouldn't it be an extension to the URL class?

Comment: Hi Joakim danielson   I agree with you we can do the same in URL too. For this case we are handling the URL as string

Comment: Yes but since it is only relevant for URL's why have it as an extension to String? What is the point of doing `"Balagurubaran".stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` for instance?

Comment: Hi Joakim danielson, "Joakim/danielson".stringByDeletingLastPathComponent

Comment: `URL(string: "Joakim/Danielson")?.deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString ?? ""`

Comment: Hi Joakim/Danielson  just i dont want to write the URL(string: "Joakim/Danielson")?.deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString  again and again   so i used this solution to simplified the logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207427/discussion-between-balagurubaran-and-joakim-danielson).

Comment: Which you can avoid by adding `var stringByDeletingLastPathComponent: String {
        return self.deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString ?? ""
    }` in an extension to `URL`